# PHP Facebook Registration

Tags: facebook

Hi i am a beginner in FACEBOOK API integration. I need to implement the facebook regisrtation for the users in my website.I have to save all of the user datas by using Facebook API.
.
 I am using the following source of code to fetch those details. At the time of registration it will show user facebook  Prefilled Information, with a register button at the bottom. After the registration Button ,there will be some friends image who have already registered in the website.I have to track those userIDs and store them under the user informations in the user table. I have been google it out for more than a day, but i can't find much solution so anyone kindly provide me some suggestion for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are so many options when you go with Facebook FacePilation plugin. Use that plugin, we will be getting all of your needs i hope.

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/facepile/